# Eigen - Concatenated matrix as a reference

Tags: c++, eigen

The following code concatenates a vector of ones to a matrix:

```
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

MatrixXd cbind1(const Eigen::Ref<const MatrixXd> X) {
  const unsigned int n = X.rows();
  MatrixXd Y(n, 1 + X.cols());
  Y << VectorXd::Ones(n), X;
  return Y;
}
```

The function copies the contents of X to Y. How do I define the function so that it avoids doing the copy and returns a reference to a matrix containing `VectorXd::Ones(n), X`?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems to me impossible. Since you do not want to concatenate a vector to **Original Matrix X**, the only difference to make is a deep copy or  shallow copy , or something like that.

Comment: I've edited my answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647219) on that matter showing that they are actually duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had followed and read ggael's answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647219/eigenref-for-concatenating-matrices) (and it appears you did, as you accepted his answer), you would have read [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html) of the docs. By modifying the example slightly, you could have written as part of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;

template<class ArgType>
struct ones_col_helper {
    typedef Matrix<typename ArgType::Scalar,
        ArgType::SizeAtCompileTime,
        ArgType::SizeAtCompileTime,
        ColMajor,
        ArgType::MaxSizeAtCompileTime,
        ArgType::MaxSizeAtCompileTime> MatrixType;
};

template<class ArgType>
class ones_col_functor
{
    const typename ArgType::Nested m_mat;

public:
    ones_col_functor(const ArgType& arg) : m_mat(arg) {};

    const typename ArgType::Scalar operator() (Index row, Index col) const {
        if (col == 0) return typename ArgType::Scalar(1);
        return m_mat(row, col - 1);
    }
};

template <class ArgType>
CwiseNullaryOp<ones_col_functor<ArgType>, typename ones_col_helper<ArgType>::MatrixType>
cbind1(const Eigen::MatrixBase<ArgType>& arg)
{
    typedef typename ones_col_helper<ArgType>::MatrixType MatrixType;
    return MatrixType::NullaryExpr(arg.rows(), arg.cols()+1, ones_col_functor<ArgType>(arg.derived()));
}

int main()
{
    MatrixXd mat(4, 4);
    mat << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16;

    auto example = cbind1(mat);

    std::cout << example << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My compiler is unable to identify the type `Index` in `one_col_functor`. Is it part of the `Eigen` namespace?

Comment: Yes, Eigen::Index

Comment: It says no type named `Index` in namespace `Eigen`. Isn't it usually something like `Eigen::VectorXd::Index`?

Comment: Are you using Eigen 3.3?

Comment: I'm using `RcppEigen`, which uses Eigen 3.2.9.

Comment: I just added `namespace Eigen { typedef std::ptrdiff_t Index; }`. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: Actually the answer to the previous question also solve that one, as seen in my [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40664512/1641621).

Comment: BTW, the line `const ArgType &m_mat` is not correct in case you nest a temporary expression. It must be `const typename ArgType::Nested m_mat`.

Comment: @ggael So the `NestByRefBit` determines if a copy should be made, which in the case of an expression (temporary or not) resolves to false so a copy is made, while in the case of a matrix is true so it's "stored" as a reference?

Comment: Yes exactly.  This is handled internally by `internal:ref_selector`. Of course, if you nest a temporary matrix, then you are screwed. For instance `auto X = cbind1((A*B).eval());` is wrong.