# Modifying values of nullary-expressions using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I do want to write a custom nullary-expression in Eigen3, which is modifyable. As described in the [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html) it seems like nullary-expression are not modifiable. Is there an easy way to get something like a modifyable custom nullary-expression?

I would like to use it to write a custom data wrapper.

Comment: You linked to what amounts to a tutorial for this. You can also look at these recent questions ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647219/eigenref-for-concatenating-matrices), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647219/eigenref-for-concatenating-matrices)) for more examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nullary-expressions are indeed read-only. For read-write expressions, you currently has to write your own expression. To this end you can start with this [tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicNewExpressionType.html) and take inspiration from the implementation of the `Transpose` expression in Eigen.