# Eigen: fast way to operate on two same-sized buffers

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a large `Eigen::ArrayXXd` and need to repeatedly operate on pairs of continuous segments of that array. Typically, I need to use operations that only involve **one** coefficient at **one** index of **each** segment (the segments always have the same size). This happens in the most performance critical portion of my code, so I'm looking for a fast solution.

One example of such operations on both segments is to get the minimum coefficient between both segments for each position. Here's an MWE for that operation:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

using Array1Xd = Array<double, 1, Dynamic>;
using Array2Xd = Array<double, 2, Dynamic>;

using Array1XdMap = Eigen::Map<Array1Xd>;

void minCoeffLoop(
    const Array1XdMap& a,
    const Array1XdMap& b,
    Array1Xd& out
){
    for ( Index i{0}; i<out.size(); ++i ){
        out[i] = std::min(a[i], b[i]);
    }
}

void minCoeffCopy(
    const Array1XdMap& a,
    const Array1XdMap& b,
    Array1Xd& out
){
    Array2Xd copy ( 2, a.size() );
    copy.row(0) = a;
    copy.row(1) = b;
    out = copy.colwise().minCoeff();
}

int main(){
    /* pretend this is some large array */
    ArrayXXd arr (100, 100);

    Index len {10};

    /* map to contiguous memory segments of that array */
    Array1XdMap
        a { &(arr(10,10)), len },
        b { &(arr(10,11)), len };
    
    a.setLinSpaced(0, len-1);
    b.setLinSpaced(len-1, 0);

    Array1Xd out (len);
    
    minCoeffLoop(a, b, out);
    std::cout << "out after loop: " << out << "\n";
    minCoeffCopy(a, b, out);
    std::cout << "out after copy: " << out << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In one function, I use a loop and `std::min`, and in the other, I copy both segments into the rows of a Matrix, which then enables me to use `Eigen`'s builtin functions (here: `.colwise().minCoeff()`).

**Is there a way to use `Eigen` functions for this situation?**

Otherwise, any comments on achieving fast operations in this situation are also appreciated.

Note: These segments can overlap, if that's important.

Note2: Concatenation via an `NullaryExpr` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647219/eigenref-for-concatenating-matrices/68747925#68747925) appears to be slower than either copying or using the raw loop.

Comment: Probably, I don't understand what you actually want to do, but in your MRE you could just do `a.min(b)`.

Comment: +1 That certainly helps already. The docs appear to know ```min``` only in the context of ```AlignedBox``` :/
I still have many other instances, where that's not quite applicable, will amend the question tmr.

Comment: I gave up on the original idea and am working around it. Your comment was nonetheless helpful :)

Comment: @RL-S Eigen's online docs seem a bit broken as of late, especially the search function. I guess doxygen can't handle Eigen's template magic. You might want to use an IDE with good autocompletion to find appropriate methods until this is fixed.

Comment: I guess it's just the (bad|good) old doxygen search function.. The `min` function is mentioned in the quick reference guide (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__QuickRefPage.html#QuickRef_Coeffwise), but could really use some visibility. I guess it would have a good chance as a PR though.