# Eigen linear regression: avoid explicit 1's column

Tags: c++, linear-regression, eigen, coefficients

I need to solve a linear system with Eigen for linear regression. Normally to compute the constant coefficient it is assumed that the data has an additional column, composed fully of 1s. Then the `solve()` can compute it correctly.

I was wondering whether there is a way to avoid having all these ones explicitly, at no additional runtime costs. For example by appending a constant vector to the data matrix or in some other way. Wen dealing with large amounts of data that would save some space and memory loads.

Comment: You could maybe use concatenation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747925/11770674
and combine it with a nullary expression, i.e. `Ones`. But it does introduce conditional statements in the code, so I'm not sure about the runtime cost.